# Integral equality involving partial derivatives

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, partial-derivative

**Update 4:** I found the following, updated integral identity:

$$\int_{l=-\infty}^\infty l \left. \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y)\right) \right\vert_{x=y=l} \mathrm{d} l = -\int_{l=-\infty}^\infty l \left. \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y)\right) \right\vert_{x=y=l} \mathrm{d} l - \int_{l=-\infty}^\infty f(l,l) \mathrm{d} l.$$

This assumes that $f$, $f_x$ and $f_y$ tend to $0$ sufficiently fast. In short, it reads $$\int_{l=-\infty}^\infty l f_x(l, l) \mathrm{d} l=  - \int_{l=-\infty}^\infty l f_y(l,l) \mathrm{d} l - \int_{l=-\infty}^\infty f(l,l) \mathrm{d} l,$$

or, even shorter, $$\int_{l=-\infty}^\infty (f + lf_x + lf_y)(l,l) \mathrm{d}l = 0.$$

I wonder how this equation can be proven using integration by parts or substitution, for two reasons: I want to learn how it works, and I want to double-check the derivation of the equation shown below.

**Update 1:** This is how I derived the equation. Start with

$$F(m,n) := \int_{l=-\infty}^{\infty} f(ml, nl) \mathrm{d} l.$$

For simplicity, assume $m,n>0$. Then

$$F + m \frac{\partial}{\partial m} F + n \frac{\partial}{\partial n} F = F + m F_m + n F_n = 0.$$

(See a proof in Update 3.) Then insert the first equation into the second:

$$ \int_{l=-\infty}^{\infty} f(ml, nl) \mathrm{d} l + m \int_{l=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial m} f(ml, nl) \mathrm{d} l + n \int_{l=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial n} f(ml, nl) \mathrm{d} l \\
 = \int_{l=-\infty}^{\infty} f(ml, nl) \mathrm{d} l + m \int_{l=-\infty}^{\infty} l f_x(ml, nl) \mathrm{d} l + n \int_{l=-\infty}^{\infty} l f_y(ml, nl) \mathrm{d} l = 0.$$

Set $m = n = 1$, voilà.

**Update 3:**

How did I find $F + m F_m + n F_n = 0$?

Start with $$F(m,n+\Delta n) = \int_{l=-\infty}^{\infty} f(ml, (n + \Delta n)l) \mathrm{d} l.$$

Substitute $x =\frac{n + \Delta n}{n}l$, which implies $l =\frac{n}{n + \Delta n}x$ and $\mathrm{d} l =\frac{n}{n + \Delta n} \mathrm{d} x.$

Then $$F(m,n+\Delta n) = \frac{n}{n + \Delta n} \int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} f(m\frac{n}{n + \Delta n} x, nx) \mathrm{d} x = \frac{n}{n + \Delta n} F(m\frac{n}{n + \Delta n},n).$$

On both sides, subtract $\frac{n}{n + \Delta n} F(m,n)$, divide by $\Delta n$, and take $\lim_{\Delta n \to 0}$. In both cases, we will use that $\frac{n}{n + \Delta n} = 1 - \frac{\Delta n}{n + \Delta n}$.

The left side gives $$\lim_{\Delta n \to 0} \frac{F(m,n+\Delta n) - \frac{n}{n + \Delta n} F(m,n)}{\Delta n} \\
= \lim_{\Delta n \to 0} \frac{F(m,n+\Delta n) -  F(m,n) + \frac{\Delta n}{n+\Delta n}F(m,n)}{\Delta n} \\
= \lim_{\Delta n \to 0} \frac{F(m,n+\Delta n) -  F(m,n)}{\Delta n} + \frac{\frac{\Delta n}{n+\Delta n}F(m,n)}{\Delta n} \\
= F_n(m,n) + \frac{F(m,n)}{n}.$$

The right side gives $$\lim_{\Delta n \to 0} \frac{\frac{n}{n + \Delta n} F(m\frac{n}{n + \Delta n},n) - \frac{n}{n + \Delta n} F(m,n)}{\Delta n} 
\\=\lim_{\Delta n \to 0} \frac{n}{n + \Delta n} \frac{ F(m\frac{n}{n + \Delta n},n) - F(m,n)}{\Delta n}.$$

This is
$$=\lim_{\Delta n \to 0} \frac{n}{n + \Delta n} \frac{ F(m - \frac{m \Delta n}{n + \Delta n},n) - F(m,n)}{\Delta n}.$$
and further, by expanding with $\frac{m}{n + \Delta n}$,
$$=\lim_{\Delta n \to 0} \frac{n}{n + \Delta n} \frac{m}{n + \Delta n} \frac{ F(m - \frac{m \Delta n}{n + \Delta n},n) - F(m,n)}{\frac{m \Delta n}{n + \Delta n}}.$$

We now define $\Delta m := -\frac{m \Delta n}{n + \Delta n}$ to find
$$=\lim_{\Delta n \to 0} \frac{n}{n + \Delta n} \frac{m}{n + \Delta n} \cdot \lim_{\Delta m \to 0} \frac{ F(m + \Delta m,n) - F(m,n)}{-\Delta m} = -\frac{m}{n} F_m(m,n).$$

Hence, $F_n(m,n) + \frac{F(m,n)}{n} = -\frac{m}{n} F_m(m,n)$ and thus $$F+mF_m+nF_n=0.$$

Comment: This cannot be true in general: suppose $f_y \equiv 0$, for example.

Comment: Do you expect that $0 = m F _m + n F _n$ should always hold? Come on... Also, slipping a derivative (or any other type of limit, as a matter of fact) under an integral sign is a very delicate process, one that most of the time fails.

Comment: Yes, indeed I hoped  that $0=mF_m+nF_n$ would hold under some reasonable assumptions on $f$. I can post my take on a proof of that later if that helps.

Comment: @Chappers: if $f_y \equiv 0$, then $f$ is constant in $y$ direction. Then it is either constant and $=0$ everywhere (for all $x$), in which case $f_x \equiv 0$ as well; or it is constant and and $\neq 0$ for at least one $x$, then my assumption of $f$ tending to $0$ sufficiently fast is violated.

Comment: @AlexM. The updated question now includes my proof that $0 = F + mF_m + nF_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually just integration by parts: or rather, let us apply the product rule to
$$ z f(z,z). $$
We find:
$$ \frac{d}{dz} (zf(z,z)) = f(z,z) + z \frac{d}{dz} f(z,z) = f(z,z) + z\partial_1 f(z,z) + z\partial_2 f(z,z), $$
where $\partial_i$ means the derivative with respect to the $i$th argument of $f$, or more explicitly,
$$ \partial_1 f(a,b) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h,b)-f(a,b)}{h} $$
(this gets around our weird Leibnizian habit of always giving every differentiation variable a name).
So in fact,
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (1+z\partial_1+z\partial_2)f(z,z) \, dz = [z f(z,z)]_{-\infty}^{\infty} = 0, $$
if $f$ decays faster than $z^{-1}$.

Comment: This is rather obvious now, but I was blinded by several wrong calculations I made before, so I did not recognize this one even after correcting them. Thanks!

Comment: So my original question can probably be generalized to $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\vec{v} \cdot z) + z \cdot \vec{v} \cdot (\vec{\nabla} f)(\vec{v} \cdot z) \, \mathrm{d}z = 0$, right? I can ask that in a separate question if that is preferred.

Comment: Now you're getting into a bit of a mess with your $z$s: are they vectors or scalars?

Comment: The $z$ are scalars just as in your example. All vectors are marked $\vec\cdot$. And all components of $\vec{v}$ are independent of $z$.